# NXOR for 2 inputs on a turing machine, in P?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, polynomial-time

**Question:**
L is the language of $\langle M,x,y\rangle$ s.t TM $M$ accepts both inputs $x$ and $y$ or doesn't accept either. Prove that given some $M$, finding 2 inputs $x$ and $y$ s.t. $\langle M,x,y\rangle\in L $ can be done in polynomial time.

**Thoughts:**
This seems strange to me that this can be done in P time as we have to somehow guess an unbounded amount of inputs for that to be true.

Comment: I'm guessing you probably want the additional restriction that $x\ne y$, otherwise $\langle M,x,x\rangle$ is a trivial solution to your problem.

Comment: More generally: Are you sure you've copied down the problem correctly?  Where did you get the problem from?

Comment: $x\ne y$ is not written in the question (it's a test). If I pick x=y then L is $\Sigma^*$ which is trivial? I got it from a test from previous years in our computational models class.

Comment: No, that doesn't mean $L$ is $\Sigma^*$.  Read the question more carefully and work through the mathematical definitions and what the input and output to your algorithm is.  Recall that your problem statement asks for an algorithm to output $x,y$, and *any* $x,y$ will do.  This question does not look like a good fit here: either it isn't copied right, or this is a problem dump of a straightforward exercise that's designed to test your understanding, and where you need to make more of an effort on your own before asking and identify a more specific question than "solve my problem for me".

Comment: @D.W. I think you can answer the question formally, having given the answer in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem didn't restrict $x$ or $y$, let $x$ be any string and let $y=x$. Then $M$ either accepts $x$ or it doesn't. If $M$ accepts $x$ (and so accepts $y$) then $\langle M, x, y\rangle\in L$. Similarly, if $M$ doesn't accept $x$, we'll also have  $\langle M, x, y\rangle\in L$. The upshot is that we can find $x, y$ in constant time.